# Strange behavior of parametrised function passed as a prop in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am probably not seeing some obvious thing right here, but i feel pretty stuck with this one.

I have a function

```
public handleTest = (testNum: number) => {
    console.log(testNum);
  };
```

And the following case: I have a component to which I want to pass this function to further use it there onCLick event.

```
<Controls handleTest={() => this.handleTest}>
 <Button label="Test1" clicked={() => this.handleTest(42)} />
</Controls>
```

The child component is the following:

```
interface IProps {
  handleTest: (type: number) => void;
}

class Controls extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
  public render() {
    const {
      handleTest
    } = this.props;

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {this.props.children}
    <button onClick={handleTest(42)} label="Test2" />
  </React.Fragment>
);
 }
}
```

The interesting thing about this case is that in case of Test2 button, it seems not to recognize the argument passed to it while it logs an object -

```
Object { dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: {…}, nativeEvent: click, type: "click", target: button.sc-bwzfXH.gonlMM, currentTarget: button.sc-bwzfXH.gonlMM, eventPhase: 3, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, timeStamp: 689, … }
```

In case of Test1 everything works correctly. I am wondering what am I doing wrong and whether it is typescript that messes things up or some mistake of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are initilizing the `<Controls />` component, the function which you are sending is something like this:

```
() => this.handleTest
```

So in the `button` Test2 you are executing nothing because last function just return a function

So if you want to solve this:

```
<Controls handleTest={(number) => this.handleTest(number)}>
 <Button label="Test1" clicked={() => this.handleTest(42)} />
</Controls>
```

Also if you do it in this way when `<Controls />` is being rendered, your function is gonna be executed and not when the user click on it. To solve this you need to change it in this way:

```
<React.Fragment>
  {this.props.children}
  <button onClick={()=>handleTest(42)} label="Test2" />
</React.Fragment>
```

To optimize just send the function. This is function injection

```
<Controls handleTest={this.handleTest}>
   <Button label="Test1" clicked={() => this.handleTest(42)} />
</Controls>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a function call to the handler, this would only work if you had curried the original function instead.

`<button onClick={handleTest(42)} label="Test2" />` instead of

`<button onClick={() => handleTest(42)} label="Test2" />`

`<button onClick={handleTest(42)} label="Test2" />` would work if `handleTest` looked like this:

```
public handleTest = (testNum: number) => () => {
  console.log(testNum);
};
```

EDIT: I would actually recommend utilizing handlers the second way, when you need to infuse an outside parameter into the handler function. By declaring a handler through 
`{() => doSomething()}`, every time you render the component that handler function will be initialized again.

Regardless, that's just a small optimization in most cases.